# Minimum distance for a cyclic code

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, coding-theory

I am given the code $C[8,4,d]$ over $\mathbb{F}_3$ with generator polynomial $g(x)=x^4 + 1$. From theory I know that the check polynomial is given by the division of $x^8 - 1$  by $x^4+1$. This gives precisely $h(x)=x^4 + 2$.

From this, I can build the following parity check matrix $H$:

$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0  & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 &0 &0 \\
0 & 1  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 &0 &0 \\
0 & 0  & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 &2 &0 \\
0 & 0  & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 &0 &2
\end{bmatrix}$

**My question is: WHAT IS THE MINIMUM DISTANCE?**

Actually, if I sum all the columns I find the vector $(3,3,3)=(0,0,0)\mod3$. So, it seems to me that $8$ columns are linearly independent, and since every set of $7$ columns is linearly  independent, I'd say that the minimum distance is 8.

Is everthing okay?

Comment: Columns 1 and 5 are scalar multiples of each other and thus form a linearly dependent set. Therefore the minimum distance cannot be higher than two. In fact, because $g(x)$ is a codeword of weight two, you don't need the check matrix to see this. Can you show (with the aid of the check matrix) that the minimum distance is at least two?

Comment: May be you need to review a few examples about linear (in)dependence from your linear algebra textbook/lecture notes?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen  I agee that 1 and 5 columns are scalar multiple of each other. But if I sum all columns, I get the $0$ vector. This is equivalent to say they're dependent, as far as I know. I can't see what is wrong.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Maybe I got it: If I have a set of 2 vectors linearly dependent, even if I add an independent vector, then the set of those three vectors is still dependent. Example: $(1,1,1),(2,2,2)$ are linearly dependent. If I add to this set also $e_1$ then of course I have $(1,1,1)+(2,2,2)+ 0 e_1=0$. So, I have to look to the "minimal" set of dependent vectors Am I right ?

Comment: So, I'm actually worong when I say in my post that every set of 7 vectors is independent. That's not true (for the reason mentioned above). Now I want to answer to your question in the first comment: 1 and 5 are scalar multiples, and any set of 2−1=1 columns is of course independent. So the min. distance is 2, right? @JyrkiLahtonen

Comment: Correct. A code with minimu distance $<2$ would have a column of all zeros in its check matrix.